# Magento 2 - Related products not showing

Tags: magento2, related-products, magento2.3.4

I try to show "Related Products, Up-Sells, and Cross-Sells ". All of them work, but "Related Products".

I thought there must be something wrong with the products which I have assigned to **Related Products**. So I assigned the same products which I have assigned to the working "Up-Sells", but there is still nothing showing.

I also checked out **Magento Blank** and **Magento Luma** Theme and cleared the cache. But there is still nothing.

I am using Magento 2.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. We use the extension Aheadworks_Wbtab which brings an own slider with "who bought this also bought". It was set to replace the "Related Products" slider.

[image]